# column names on grouped DataFrame output to CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a `dataFrame` from a large questionnaire, I'm generating summaries by aggregating the data on different axis by doing:

```
df.groupby(group_name).agg([np.mean, np.std, np.count_nonzero])
```

This generates a column with mean, std, and count per question in my questionnaire. The names of each column in the grouped `dataFrame` are a tuple `(original_column_name, function_applied)`

The problem is that when I output to CSV (using `to_csv()`) the column names are outputted as a tuple i.e. `('gender', 'mean'), ('gender', 'std')` where ideally I would like something like `gender_mean` & `gender_std`

How can I process these column names before output to CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas 0.8.1, try this:

```
group_df = df.groupby(group_name).agg([np.mean, np.std, np.count_nonzero])
group_df.rename(None, lambda coltuple: '_'.join(coltuple), False, True)
```

See [the DataFrame documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename) for more details.

Comment: Brilliant, this works. NB: there is a small typo (lambda) buy SO does not let me edit it as deemed to small < 6 chars

Comment: Oops, blub blubbity blub. :-)